# grails - upload file in gsp (disappear after clicking cancel)

Tags: grails, gsp

I have to upload a file in my project. But when I cancel the dialog box, the previously uploaded file is disappearing. Is there a way to maintain the first chosen file even after I cancel the dialog box.

Here's my code

```
<div class="input-field" id="uploadAuditReport">
    <label class="active">Upload Audit Report *</label>
    <input type="file" id="reportFileData" name="reportFileData" required-error="Please upload a file" class="m-b-10 card-panel" style="bottom-border: dotted 1px" pattern="^.*(xls|xlsx|doc|pdf|docx|ods|jpg|jpeg|png|XLS|XLSX|DOC|PDF|DOCX|ODS|JPG|JPEG|PNG)$" pattern-error="File must be in xls, xlsx, doc, pdf, docx, ods, jpg/ jpeg, and png format" required="" filesize="30000000" filesize-error="File must not exceed a file size of 30 MB." >                                      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.  See: [input type="file", clearing file after clicking cancel in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798993/input-type-file-clearing-file-after-clicking-cancel-in-chrome)

- you can't detect when cancel is clicked
- you can't do anything about it
- different browsers handle it in different ways