# File input type disappears on Chrome

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, input

I have a form with `<input type="file">`. I was doing a couple of tests, I found out that on Chrome when someone chooses a file and decides to change the file they had chosen already, and press the cancel button the file path of the previous file disappears or sometimes when you open a new tab while on the form.

How can this problem be solved?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>


 <form>
  <input type="file" name="">
 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it's by design, although not a good design. It's offers you a way to **reset** the input element.

Comment: It is default behavior of file input control, you can not alter it - it may be due to security reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input type="file", clearing file after clicking cancel in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798993/input-type-file-clearing-file-after-clicking-cancel-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change it, it is impossible. This is something that it does by default. It doesn't let you detect when the `cancel` button is clicked, so you can't do anything about it. It's all because of the browser design.