# React Hook Form - required prop is rejecting data that is set with setvalue

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, react-hook-form

I am trying to create a file input with an image preview in react hook form while also preventing my browser from clearing a selected image when the user presses cancel. More info on that here:

[input type="file", clearing file after clicking cancel in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798993/input-type-file-clearing-file-after-clicking-cancel-in-chrome%5C%5C)

To do this I save the current picture onClick and then if the browser clears the file onChange I run setValue to reset the value to what it was before. When I click submit with required enabled the form is rejected but both watch and getValues say that the field is filled.

```
const {register, handleSubmit, resetField, getValues, setValue, watch, formState: {errors, dirtyFields}} = useForm()
console.log(getValues("file"))
console.log(watch("file"))

let fileElement: any;

function fileClicked(event: any) {
   console.log('File Clicked')
   fileElement = event.target.files;
} 

function onChangePicture(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        if(!e.target.files) return;
        if(e.target.files.length < 1) {
            console.log('set value ran')
            setValue("file", fileElement);
        }
        // Below if statement is logic for setting image preview, ignore. 
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
            setImgData(reader.result as string);
          });
          reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    };

<input
    id="fileInput"
    type="file"
    onClick={(e) => fileClicked(e)}
    {...register('file', {required: true, onChange: (e) => onChangePicture(e)})}
/>
```

Picture of console below. I added an image, then clicked to add another but pressed cancel, and then pressed submit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrY7L.jpg)